# Trying to send Email from spring server.Error is creating bean with name 'hourlyJob': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception

Tags: java, spring, listener, jakarta-mail, servletcontextlistener

Error creating bean with name 'hourlyJob':

```
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender com.email.job.HourlyJob.mailSenderObj; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4853)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**HourlyJob.java**
In this class I connected with database to fetch a table "order_info" and checking upon shipment date I tried to send email.

```
    @Repository
    @Transactional
    public class HourlyJob implements Runnable {

        static String emailToRecipient, emailSubject, emailMessage;
        static final String emailFromRecipient = "abc@gmail.com";

        static ModelAndView modelViewObj;

        @Autowired
        private JavaMailSender mailSenderObj;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do your daily job here.
        System.out.println("Job trigged by scheduler");
        try
        {
        // create our mysql database connection
        String myDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test";
        Class.forName(myDriver);
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, "root", "");
        // our SQL SELECT query. 
        // if you only need a few columns, specify them by name instead of using "*"
        String query = "SELECT * FROM order_info";
        // create the java statement
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        // execute the query, and get a java resultset
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        // iterate through the java resultset
        while (rs.next())
        {

            Date shipmentDate=rs.getDate("shipment_date");
            Date today = new Date();
            long diff=shipmentDate.getTime()-today.getTime();
            long days = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(diff);
            if(Math.abs(days)==1)
            {
                System.out.println("SHIPMENT DATE "+shipmentDate+"        Day difference is :"+days);
                emailSubject = "Order Notification";
                emailMessage = "Please see The following order date.";
                emailToRecipient = "1205085.msss@ugrad.cse.buet.ac.bd";
                // send email 
                mailSenderObj.send(new MimeMessagePreparator() 
                {
                    public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {

                        MimeMessageHelper mimeMsgHelperObj = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true, "UTF-8");             
                        mimeMsgHelperObj.setTo(emailToRecipient);
                        mimeMsgHelperObj.setFrom(emailFromRecipient);               
                        mimeMsgHelperObj.setText(emailMessage);
                        mimeMsgHelperObj.setSubject(emailSubject);

                        // Determine If There Is An File Upload. If Yes, Attach It To The Client Email              
                    }
                });
                System.out.println("\nMessage Send Successfully.... Hurrey!\n");
            }

        }
        st.close();
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
      }

    }
    }
```

**BackgroundJobManager.java**
In this class I implemented ServletContextListener to schedule **HourJob.java** each minute.

```
    @WebListener
    public class BackgroundJobManager implements ServletContextListener 
    {
        // scheduler
        private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;

        @Override
        public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {

            scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
            // here we schedule HourlyJob 
            scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new HourlyJob(), 0, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        }

        @Override
        public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
            scheduler.shutdownNow();
         }

    }
```

**spring-servlet.xml**
This is the dispatcher servlet. Here I defined mailSender bean.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

        <!-- bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        </bean -->
        <!-- where the front controller search for controllers -->


        <bean id="tilesViewResolver" 
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver">
        </bean>

        <bean id="tilesConfigurer" 
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
            <property name="definitions">
                <list>
                    <value>/WEB-INF/layout/default.xml</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="multipartResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">

             <!-- setting maximum upload size 15 MB -->
            <property name="maxUploadSize" value="15728640" />

        </bean>

        <!-- mail staff -->

            <!-- Spring Email Sender Bean Configuration -->
        <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
            <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
            <property name="port" value="587" />
            <property name="username" value="abc@gmail.com" />
            <property name="password" value="********" />
            <property name="javaMailProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
                    <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
                    <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
                    <prop key="mail.smtp.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop>
                    <prop key="mail.smtp.socketFactory.port">465</prop>
                    <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>


        <!-- mail staff -->

        <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
    </beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

It says you have no bean of type `org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender` which is weird because it looks like you have configured that in your xml as you've mentioned, do you have getters and setters for `JavaMailSender mailSenderObj` ?  `setMailSenderObj(JavaMailSender mailSenderObj)` you need getters and setters for private fields. I think you don't for protected with the new Spring version. Otherwise ensure that your `spring-servlet.xml` is indeed creating those beans. Typically you don't mix servlet stuff with spring stuff so not sure what you are up to there. I recommend only using annotations if you can and just using the latest version of Spring. Good luck.